# How to use python pysqldf for simple query

Tags: python, sql

I am getting error by using a very simple query as follows.

```
q1 = """

SELECT   ad.hadm_id, i.icustay_id


FROM

df_admin ad
df_icustays i
"""
print(pysqldf(q1).head())
```

It is just extracting two columns from two different dataframes .

```
Error:
PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "df_icustays": syntax error [SQL: '\n\nSELECT   ad.hadm_id, i.icustay_id\n\n\nFROM\n\ndf_admin ad\n\n\n\ndf_icustays i\n\n\n'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Comment: Missing comma before `df_icustays`

Comment: It still pops out the same error as with coma.